# how to use jQuery "autocomplete source" inside JavaScript for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, autocomplete

I have some jQuery code:

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({

            source: [
                "Test0", "Test1", "Test2", "Test3"
            ]
        });
```

instead of static source I need to read it from array.. I am getting it, and now want to give it out with for loop like this but it doesn't work!

```
 for (var i = 0; i < orgUnits.length; i++) {

            debugger;
            var city = orgUnits[i];

            $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({

                source: [
                   city
                ]
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: orgUnits
});
```

Comment: if i have such a array var orgUnits = [[],[]]; can I call it like this?????: for (var i = 0; i < orgUnits.length; i++) {
                $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
                    source: "City: " + orgUnits[i][0] + ", Firma: " + orgUnits[i][1]
                });
            }

Comment: @RagimsRagimovs, Could you post in your question the structure of the `orgUnits` object?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  $(function() {
    var orgUnits = ["Test","Test2","Test3","Test4","Test5"];
    var compiledList;
    for (var i = 0; i < orgUnits.length; i++) {
            var city = orgUnits[i];
            compiledList.push(city);
        }
       $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
      source: compiledList
    });
  });
```

The big problem I saw was trying to use "[city]" as a source instead of "city" itself. It is already an array, so you don't need to define the array with the brackets.

What your code is really doing is resetting autocomplete each time to a single string. What you want to do is compile the array and then pass it to the autocomplete method.

You can skip the for loop if you just pass the orgUnits array itself.